# Can't see URL's list. Django 1.9.5, ListView

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

Dear friends in community. I'm new in Python and Django. I using Django 1.9.5. I tried to represent navigation list from model. But I don't see list of URLs on the page. Can anybody explain me, what I do wrong?

**Model:**

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class mdl_StaticPages(models.Model):
    seo_Title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    seo_Keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    seo_Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    seo_Meta = models.TextField(blank=True)
    page_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    page_progName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    page_Content = RichTextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Static pages'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Static pages'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.seo_Title
```

**View:**

```
class StaticMenuList(ListView):
 context_object_name = 'StaticPageURLs'
 queryset = mdl_StaticPages.objects.all().order_by('page_Name')
 template_name = "master.html"
```

and **Master.html:**

```
{% for ListMenu in StaticPageURLs %}
     <a href=" {{ ListMenu.page_progName|lower }}/ ">{{ ListMenu.page_Name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

I expected to see list of URLs, but I see empty area...

Comment: Your code looks OK. Just as a pointer, you should have a look at the [style guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/). Generally, variables should be `lower_case_underscored` and not `camelCase`. Same for methods. Classes should use `InitialCaps`. Have you checked to make sure your queryset actually contains objects? Is the `master.html` template definitely correctly loaded?

Comment: Is the template named `Master.html` or `master.html`? Are you sure you don't have another template named `master.html`?

Comment: @Selcuk, "master.html" is "master.html". From lower case letter.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony, irony of situation it that I have link on this, "master" page. Urls.py: **url(r'^statics/\w+$', views.StaticMenuList.as_view(), name="Staticmenus"),** 
from master.html: **<a href="{% url 'Staticmenus'  %}">test link</a>**

and if I click on this link, page reloaded and I can see list of URL's.